# VS 2017 Web Load Test Assembly not found exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio, testing, load-testing, fusion

I have a Web Load Test with a we test in it.  It compiles as expected and it looks like the correct assemblies with correct versions are in the `bin\` folder.

Once it's built I run it and get the following error:

```
Request failed: Exception occurred: Could not load file or assembly 'WebAndLoadTestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I look in the Fusion logs I can see that it is looking for the assembly in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/...`.  Obviously it's not there.

Why isn't it (whatever it is that's looking for the assembly) looking in the `bin\Debug\` folder?

---

**Fusion Log Entry**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20/04/2017 @ 16:16:17) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = WebAndLoadTestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = QTAgent32_40.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20/04/2017 @ 16:16:17) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = WebAndLoadTestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = QTAgent32_40.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/WebAndLoadTestProject1/WebAndLoadTestProject1.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```